# How to read what a process is sending to /dev/net/tun?

Tags: networking, kernel, network-interface

I altered OpenVPN's client source code to send IP packets through my app, not through the operating system. Therefore I'm creating the IP packets by hand (using libtins). I can see that they arrive encrypted at OpenVPN server every second (because I send them every second). However, for some reason, on the server side, they don't appear if I do `tcpdump` on `tun0`. This is possibly happening because OpenVPN server is passing a malformed packet to tun0 and therefore tun0 reject is and doesn't pass it as a packet.

How can I intercept what's being written to `/dev/net/tun` so I can see what OpenVPN server is writing?